# Get dynamic input field values in Aura

Tags: aura, ui

I'm building a dynamic custom UI which is configurable via custom metadatatype.
I declare field label, datatype, position(left/right columns on UI) etc on the CMD.

I populate fields using aura:iteration of the UI like below,

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.myMetadata}" var="md">
                                <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
                                    <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread">
                                        
                                        <lightning:layoutItem size="5" class="slds-p-around_medium slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning:input type="{!md.Datatype__c}" name="{!md.Field_Label__c}" aura:id="{!md.Field_Label__c}"
                                                             dateStyle="short" label="{!md.Field_Label__c}"/>
                                        </lightning:layoutItem>
                                        
                                    </lightning:layout>
                                </lightning:layoutItem>
                            </aura:iteration>
```

If I create 10 records in CMD, I get 10 input fields on the UI.
I want to capture all the input data from the UI. I tried the dynamic aura:id but didn't work.
I came across an idea for dynamic aura:id here and assuming this wouldn't work, https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E8fBQAS

Wanted to see if there are any other alternatives to capture user input data for dynamic fields? Please let me know.

Comment: where do you want to capture them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm), you cannot set aura:id value dynamically.

> aura:id doesn't support expressions. You can only assign literal
> string values to aura:id.

But you could manage to implement the following approach:

- Set same aura:id for all the `lightning:input` elements; so when you query by this ID, you will get an array of these elements [*in the same order they are rendered in the page*].
- Loop thru this array and use `v.label` or `v.value` to identify the input element label or to get its value correspondingly. Rest of the Javascript code in your component can be made dynamic based on these values. [*or you may use some other attributes to manage your logic*]. [Ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm)

Disclaimer: I'm not recommending this approach as a best practice and in fact, this might not be suitable for building a generic re-usable component. But, you can achieve some degree of dynamic handling for individual aura component using this approach.

Comment: Thank you  @arut. This helps. Looks like this is the only way.